# Oracle ZFS Storage Appliance: Retrieve performance statistics (IOPS, Throughput, Latency) through REST api

Tags: oracle, zfs

I have read through Oracle ZFS's REST api doc (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51475_01/html/E52433/makehtml-id-4.html#scrolltoc) and did not really find clear info about how to request IOPS, ThroughPut, and latency counters. There is a CLI command to do so. The command "Zpool iostat" and "zpool iostat -v" (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gammt/index.html) returns statistics for pools and virtual volumes, respectively. I am looking for equivalent REST commands to retrieve the same info.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your ZFS server.  Is it an Oracle ZFS storage appliance?  Is it something you've put together running ZFS on Linux?  If it is an Oracle storage appliance, Google is your friend:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51475_01/html/E52433/index.html

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Yes, it's Oracle ZFS storage appliance. I have spent quite a few hours to figure this out. I have also gone through the REST api doc that you suggested. I have not found any clear instructions on how to retrieve performance stats.